# Looping through two vars completely in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to make boxes that cover the entire Earth 1 degree latitude by 1 degree longitude.  Using two nested while loops should work, I thought, but I only get the longitudes to loop.

Here's what I have:

```
$lat_min = -90;
$lat_max = -89;
$lng_min = -180;
$lng_max = -179;

while($lat_max <= '90' ) {
    while($lng_max <= '180' ){
        echo $lat_min.'   '.$lat_max.'   '.$lng_min.'   '.$lng_max.'<br>';

        $lng_min++;
        $lng_max++;
     }

     $lat_min++;
     $lat_max++;

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure?  The last 180 lines would look like the latitude is not changing, but the output is tens of thousands of lines.  You might just not be looking back far enough in the output.

Comment: I had it output to a webpage, and it's not longer than 180 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me, but just in case and probably for better readability, remove the quotes in your conditions

```
$lat_min = -90;
$lat_max = -89;
$lng_min = -180;
$lng_max = -179;

while($lat_max <= 90 ) {
    while($lng_max <= 180 ){
        echo $lat_min.'   '.$lat_max.'   '.$lng_min.'   '.$lng_max.'<br>';

        $lng_min++;
        $lng_max++;
     }

     $lat_min++;
     $lat_max++;

    }
```

EDIT:

```
<?php
for($i = 1; $i <= 180; $i++) {
        for($j = 1; $j <= 180; $j++) {
                echo $i .' ' . $j .'<br/>';
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that's how I started and that doesn't fix it.  Still only loops through the longitude.

Comment: Thank you!  For clarification, why don't the while loops work the same as the for loops?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you start your loop with -90, but the for loop I wrote and your while loop are quite different

Comment: the `for` loop forces the loop to continue, `while` only works when it returns a value of true. Not a big difference, but the `for` loop will be much faster (Ok milliseconds, but it adds up.) But your code would loop over both , but you would only KNOW it went over the `$lng` you are not `echo`'ing the `$lat`, add `echo $lat_min.'   '.$lat_max.'   '.$lng_min.'   '.$lng_max.'<br>';
` under the `$lat_max++` and you'll see it is working.